# why the prevent form submit code doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    if($("#field-huima-0-value").val()=='' && $(".link-field .form-text").val() =='')
    $("#edit-submit").click(function(){
       alert("you must at least enter one value！"); 
    });
});
```

**field-huima-0-value** and **.link-field .form-text** are two input text boxes id and class.

when the two input text boxes is null. i click the submit button. the alert box shows, then i click ok. the form still be submitted. but now,i want to prevent the form  from   submitting. so i add the `return false;` under the `alert` line. it can prevent the form submitting.but when i type a value into one input boxes of the them, when click the button. it still shows the alert box.

Comment: The validation should happen on `submit`, not `click`, and the `if` statement needs to be in event handler with a `return false` following the case that matches a non-validation.

Comment: Also see preventDefault(). http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you code needs some modifications, kindly check this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#edit-submit").click(function() {
     if(!$("#field-huima-0-value").val() && !$(".link-field .form-text").val()) {
         alert("you must at least enter one value！"); 
         return false;
     }
     return true;
  });    
});
```

this code will attach the check function to the click event of your submit button, and only returns false if the check didn't succeed.

**Update:** I've updated the above code ans tested it, and now working fine, also I've made you a sample to test this code, kindly follow this link: http://jsfiddle.net/6egtW/1/

let me know what happened.

Comment: i put you code in, a werid thing happened. the form can't be submitted. when i click the submit button many times, the form can't be submitted. why? if i delete the   return false; the form can be submitted

Comment: I've updated my answer, kindly give it a try now and let me know what happened, thanks.

Comment: it'ok. many thanks. but i don't know why i mnust be add else
       {
           return true;
       }

Comment: to let the called button knows that it can continue executing the attached code.

just don't forget to "Mark as answer" if it really fixed your problem. :)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are checking the values when the page loads, not when you click the button.

Check the values in the `click` event instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

  $("#edit-submit").click(function(){
    if($("#field-huima-0-value").val() == '' && $(".link-field .form-text").val() =='') {
      alert("you must at least enter one value！");
      return false;
    }
  });

});
```

Note: If you require both fields to be filled in, you should use the `||` operator instead of `&&` in the condition.

Also consider to do the validation using the `submit` event. The difference is that when you do the check on the `click` event you will only validate the form if it's the button that is used to post the form. If there is another way of posting the form (using the enter key for example), the validation will not happen.

Comment: when i changed it to submit. it doesn't work, why? the jquery version is 1.26

Comment: zhuanzhou: The `submit` event is triggered on the form, not the button.

Comment: got it. but there was a werid thing happened,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6534728/a-weird-thing-when-submit-a-form

Answer (score 1):

1. Check values on click
2. return false on click if dont want submit
3. you can use .submit() to submit form

Comment: Kindly check my posted answer and see if it follows these steps or not :)

Comment: ops, yes :) +1 to your answer.

Comment: Appreciate it :), +1 for your organaized answer too, but as a suggestion, consider proofing your points with some lines of code, this will proof your point more than just listing the required steps.
also online code sites like www.JsFiddle.com are amazing. give them a try, and hope to see you in the lands of the 1000s people soon :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#edit-submit").click(function() {
        if($("#field-huima-0-value").val()=='' || $(".link-field .form-text").val() =='') {
           alert("you must at least enter one value！"); 
        });
    }
});
```

Try that - you need to run the code in the `click` event, your `if` statement wasn't containing the code I think you meant it to, and was testing to see if both fields were empty, not if either field was empty.